# SWIFT: Could not delete Plist file after initial write / deleting

Tags: swift, plist

I try to update my plist when values changed.
But only at the first time, when there is no plist file, I could successfuly save my data with writeToFile:

```
    var initDic: NSMutableDictionary = [
        "gMaxRootDir":        gMaxRootDir
        "gKeepNumber":        gKeepNumber
    ]


    if plistExist {
        var error: NSError?
        if !filemgr.removeItemAtPath(plistpath, error: &error) {
            println("plistpath: Remove failed: \(error!.localizedDescription)")
        }
    }

    if initDic.writeToFile(plistpath, atomically: false) == false {
        println("plistpath: Save failed")
    }
```

Is something locking the file after creation and deleting again? I didn't get it overwritten. So even an update of the data would be fine.

Answer (score -1):

Use getter and setter. 
Get all old data and save new !!!
In example you have 2 rows in plist file: userNumber and userName

```
func getUserNumber() -> Int{
        var userNumber = 0
        let paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true) as NSArray
        let documentsDirectory = paths.objectAtIndex(0) as! NSString
        let path = documentsDirectory.stringByAppendingPathComponent("fileName.plist")

        var myDict = NSDictionary(contentsOfFile: path)
        if let dict = myDict {
            userNumber = dict.objectForKey("userNumber") as! Int
        }
        return userNumber
    }




func setUserName(userName: String){
        let paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true) as NSArray
        let documentsDirectory = paths.objectAtIndex(0) as! NSString
        let path = documentsDirectory.stringByAppendingPathComponent("fileName.plist")

        var dict: NSMutableDictionary = ["userNumber": getUserNumber()]
        dict.setObject(userName, forKey: "userName")
        dict.writeToFile(path, atomically: false)
        let resultDictionary = NSMutableDictionary(contentsOfFile: path)
    }
```

It is not best solution for this problem but it is work !!!
If you could use CoreData and save your data in local data base

Good luck

Comment: After inserting your code, this runs fine. After changing it to my belongings it doesn't work. After a long long time in adding one statement by the next I found out, that you could not save a type NSURL in this plist. So without that type even my old version works fine. Thank you for the hints.